# При фиксации блока он перекрывает другой и уезжает влево

Tags: шаблоны, форматирование, html, css, разметка

Всем доброго времени суток!
Возникла вот такая проблема:
На сайте в шапке два блока. Один хочу зафиксировать. Если я ставлю position:relative, то отображается как надо. Если relative меняю на fixed, то второй блок поднимается в самый верх и залазит под первый (который зафиксирован). Если указать margin, то опускаются почему-то оба блока! В фаербаге всё это видно. Но не пойму, почему так!
Сайт http://recenzo.ru/
Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Вот здесь посмотрите, в чем разница position: fixed от position: relative http://htmlbook.ru/css/position

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/zqvwyabg/

HTML:

```
<div class="block-fixed">Block fixed</div>
<header>HEADER</header>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-size: 20px;
     color: #fff;
}
.block-fixed{
    width: 100%;
    background: #008000;
    position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;   
    line-height: 50px;    
}

header{
    background: #ccc;
    min-height: 3000px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Даже не знал про этот ресурс. Очень полезный. Буду осваивать. И пример Ваш отлично работает. Но по аналогии свой не смог победить. Вот что получилось: http://jsfiddle.net/zqvwyabg/1/

Что не так?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/36bLkbpt/